# Minimize combined variance of multiple measurements with known (but varying) variance

Tags: mean-square-error, measurement-theory

I have multiple measurements for the same property but with different but known uncertainty (variance). And I would like to combine that measurements in a way that I get as close to the real value as possible (minimizing variance). We can assume the error to be Gaussian distributed and to be unbiased.

Example situation:
I've got 3 sensors of the same type. Each of them measures the same property (e.g. rotation in same axis). This results in vector x = { x1, x2, x3 }. But each of them has another known, static variance (e.g. v = { v1, v2, v3}). Now I would like to combine the measurements in a way, that minimizes variance (mean square error).

I assume that I can just multiply x by a matrix F, which gives me the optimal estimate.
That means it minimizes: (v F)².

But, I don't know how to calculate matrix F. How to do that?

Stefan

--- EDIT ---

The measurements are of course correlated (as they measure the same property)! And I can also calculate a covariance matrix...

Comment: The fact that they measure the same property has nothing to do with whether they're correlated, unless that property is random. I was under the impression that you're measuring a determinate property, and the measurements are affected by random errors.

Comment: If all measurements correlate (coefficient >0) with the real value, don't they have to correlate with each other, too?

Comment: "The measurements are of course correlated (as they measure the same property)! And I can also calculate a covariance matrix..." but do you suppose that errors of measurements are also correlated ?

Comment: The errors are/can be correlated, too. As e.g. the same type sensor may be affected by the same external influence.

Comment: @Stefan: Unless I'm misreading you, that's a fundamental misunderstanding of correlation and independence. As long as the "real value" is a determinate property and not itself random, the correlation of all random variables with it vanishes; there is no such thing as the measurements correlating with the real value. This follows immediately by applying linearity: $\langle xx_i\rangle-\langle x\rangle\langle x_i\rangle=x\langle x_i\rangle-x\langle x_i\rangle=0$, where $x$ is the "real value".

Comment: @joriki: Maybe I mixed things up... We have 1. a real value 'y'; 2. three measurements x_1, x_2, y_3, which consist of the real value plus some error / residual x_n = y + e_n . The measurement errors are assumed to be Gaussian distributed (for simplicity). The measurements are of course correlated to each other, as all of them contain "y". The errors e_n MAY be correlated, in this cases they most probably are. For example the ambient temperature affects the readings of all sensors and thus cause a correlation of their errors.

Comment: @Stefan: I don't know what else to write. It seems you didn't take in my above comment. You keep repeating that something is "of course" the case when I've stated several times that it isn't. The $y$ drops out in the correlation due to linearity, as above:$$
\begin{align}
\langle x_ix_j\rangle-\langle x_i\rangle\langle x_j\rangle&=\langle (y+e_i)(y+e_j)\rangle-\langle y+e_i\rangle\langle y+e_j\rangle\\&=y^2+y\langle e_j\rangle+\langle e_i\rangle y+\langle e_ie_j\rangle-(y+\langle e_i\rangle)(y+\langle e_j\rangle)\\&=\langle e_ie_j\rangle-\langle e_i\rangle\langle e_j\rangle\;.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @joriki: Correct, I actually did not understand the fomula in your comment above. I therefore tried to repeat my thoughts to verify, if you still think it's wrong. -- My main problem with the formula is/was the notation, thought. $\langle x x_i\rangle$ means a vector of length 1, with it's value "$x$ multiplied by $x_i$". Right? -- I will now try to understand the longer form... I'll need a moment for that.

Comment: @Stefan: No, sorry, perhaps I should have explained the notation; it's common in physics. $\langle z\rangle$ denotes the expected value of $z$, otherwise also denoted by $E[z]$, $\mathbb E[z]$ or $\bar z$.

Comment: Ah!!! Ok, expected value E[x]. Now it's starts making sense... And you probably refer to the definition of the covariance (using the $x_i$ and $x_j$ instead of the usual X and Y): $cov(x_i,x_j) = E[( x_i - E[x_i]) * ( y_i - E[y_i] )] = E[ x_i * x_j ] - E[x_i] * E[x_j]$

Comment: @Stefan: Yes, I wrote "correlation" because you kept claiming that the measurements are correlated, but what I calculated was the covariance; the correlation is the covariance scaled by the standard deviations, and of course the scaling doesn't change the fact that it's zero.

Comment: Well, if you are really correct with that long explanation/formula above, that would mean, that $corr(x_i,y_i)=\frac{cov(x_i,y_i)}{(var(x_i) * var(x_j))^0.5}=0$ since $cov(x_i,x_j)=0$

Comment: Ok, that was nonsense. But actually $cov(x_i,x_j)$ would depend only on the error residuals, not the real value. Hm... need to think about that..

Comment: Ok, I checked myself that $cov(x_i, x) = <x_i x> - <x_i><x> = <(y+e_i)*y> - <y+e_i><y> = <y^2 + y*e_i> - <y+e_i> * y = y² + y * <e_i> - y² - y * <e_i> = 0$ when $x = y$ (real value) and $x_i = y + e_i$ (measurement with gaussian noise). This means I have no covariance (and therefore correlation) between my measurements and my real value, correct? Is that, what you wanted to say. If so, I understood now. But I actually wonder what covariance/correlation  is all about in that case... What does it actually mean?

Comment: I read the wikipedia article and found that covariance measures the "coherence" or "correlation" between two random values. In fact I was regarding the "real value" of the measurement as a random variable (e.g. changing value when time passes, with more or less known distribution), too. But for multiple measurements of the same property - at the same time -, it's static / non random.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you speak only of the three individual variances and not of the covariances of the measurements, I'll assume that you're implicitly assuming that the measurements are independent.

The variance of the combined estimator $\sum_iw_ix_i$ with $\sum_iw_i=1$ is $\sum_iw_i^2v_i$. You can optimize the weights $w_i$ using a Lagrange multiplier; the objective function is $\sum_iw_i^2v_i-\lambda\sum_iw_i$, and setting the derivative with respect to $w_j$ to zero yields $2w_jv_j=\lambda$. Thus, the optimal weights are inversely proportional to the variances, and normalization leads to

$$w_j=\frac{v_j^{-1}}{\sum_iv_i^{-1}}\;.$$

[*Edit in response to comment:*]

If the covariances are known and non-zero, the variance of a linear combination $w^\top x$ is $w^\top\Sigma w$, with $\Sigma$ the covariance matrix. Then the same Lagrange multiplier approach of minimizing the objective function $w^\top\Sigma w-\lambda\sum_iw_i$ leads to $2\Sigma w=\lambda e$, where $e$ is the vector with all entries $1$. Generally $\Sigma$ will be invertible, so this yields $w=\lambda\Sigma^{-1}e/2$, and normalization yields

$$
w=\frac{\Sigma^{-1}e}{e\Sigma^{-1}e}\;.
$$

Comment: Yes, I noticed that covariances are needed, as the measurements are in fact correlated. So I would have a covariance matrix... Do you also have a solution with known covariances?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the variation with covariance matrix!

Comment: I am new to the Lagrange multiplier. I have a question: Shouldn't g be the (sum of Wi) - 1? I was reading this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier

Comment: @Tarik: It doesn't matter, since that constant doesn't appear in the equations that you get by differentiating the objective function.

Comment: Shouldn't the partial derivative over lambda be the sum(Wi) - 1?

Comment: @Tarik: Here it's minus that sum; that's just a sign change in $\lambda$, and $\lambda$ is arbitrary. I recommend going through the steps, once the way you think it "should" be done and once the way I did it, and try to understand why the differences you noted (additive constant and sign change) don't affect the end result.

Comment: We are minimizing subject to Sum(wi) = 1. This is equivalent to Sum(wi) - 1 = 0. So lambda g(x) becomes lambda(Sum(wi) - 1) which partial derivative with respect to lambda is Sum(wi) - 1.

Comment: @Tarik: Yes. But why are you interested in the partial derivative with respect to $\lambda$?

Comment: To solve $ \nabla_{x,y,\lambda} \mathcal{L}(x , y, \lambda)=0. $ as per Wikipedia article. I am not trying to argue here. Just understand.

Comment: @Tarik: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a reference and tutorial for typesetting math on this site. (Note in particular that math is enclosed in single or double dollar sings, not in <math> tags.)

Comment: @Tarik: I see. If that's how you learned Lagrange multipliers, yes, then you need to write the Lagrange term as you wrote it. This is a bit redundant, though, since differentiating with respect to $\lambda$ just gives you the constraint that you already knew. The way I think about it, you solve $ \nabla_{x,y} \mathcal{L}(x , y, \lambda)=0$ under the given constraint, but yes, if you want to re-derive the constraint by differentiating with respect to lambda, then you need to plug in $\lambda$ times the exact constraint function.

Comment: "This is a bit redundant, though, since differentiating with respect to λ just gives you the constraint that you already knew." Yes indeed. But then, isn't the constraint $\sum_i w_i = 1$? which is equivalent to $\sum_i w_i - 1 = 0$. How is the 1 disappearing from the constraint? This is what has left me clueless up to now.

Comment: @Tarik: That may be a misunderstanding. I agreed with your previous comment that if you want to re-derive the constraint by differentiating $\mathcal L$ with respect to $\lambda$, you need to use the entire constraint function, as you wrote, you can't drop the $1$. I dropped the $1$ because I don't do it that way; I just use the constraint as it is, $\sum_iw_i=1$, I don't rederive it by differentiating $\mathcal L$ with respect to $\lambda$, and then it doesn't matter whether I keep the $1$ in $\mathcal L$ or drop it since it drops out anyway when I differentiate with respect to $x$ and $y$.

Comment: OK, I went through the whole thing again and I finally understood. Thanks for your patience!