# I have N measurements whose uncertainties are unknown. What is the variance?

Tags: statistics, variance

I measured something $N$ times using different measurement techniques. Each measurement technique $i$ has a known variance $\sigma_i^2$. So every measurement is $x_i = \hat x + \epsilon_i$ where $\hat x$ is the true value and $\epsilon_i$ is pulled from a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2_i$.

Ok, I have all these measurements. Now I want to know the variance of my measurements taken together, taking into account the fact that I know the variance of all the measurement techniques. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can just treat them as sum of normally distributed variables, which is extensively written down in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables).

In short, if $X \sim N(x,\sigma_x^2)$ and $Y \sim N(y,\sigma_y^2)$ and $X,Y$ are independent, then $$X+Y \sim N(x+y, \sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2)$$

---

In your case you have the measurements $X_i \sim N(x, \sigma_i^2)$, but you don't know the actual value $x$ (which is why you're doing the measurements.) Now In order to find $x$, you probably want to take the average of all of them, that is $\hat x = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$

If we now treat $\hat x$ as a random variable, we can determine its variance by using the formula above, and we get:

$$n \hat x = \sum_i X_i \sim N(nx, \sum_i \sigma_x^2)$$

Now as a last step you have to "solve" for $\hat x$ which is not difficult. (Use that $Var(aX) = a^2 Var(X)$, and $E[aX] = aE[x]$)

Comment: I am a bit confused by this answer. Why a sum?

Comment: Don't you want to take the mean of those measurements, ans know the "total" variance? The mean is nothing but a scaled sum.

Comment: I can see where you're coming from, but I'm not really sure how to now use it

Comment: I extended my answer, I hope this answers what you were looking for. You basically just iteratively apply the formula for $X$ and $Y$ that I showed in the first place.

Comment: So $\rm{Var}(n \hat x) = n^2\rm{Var}(\hat x) = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_i \sigma^2_x$?

Comment: So does that mean that the actual measurements $x_i, \; i=1\ldots N$ don't come into the measurement of the variance at all? That seems odd to me...

Comment: The last equality is not quite correct, you get $Var(\hat x) = \frac 1{n^2} \sum_i \sigma_i^2$.

Comment: Regarding your last comment: You *could* do that, but that would only be useful if you did not know the $\sigma_i^2$ in the first place. But because you do know them you actually already have a *lot* more information than what you'd have with only the measurements.

Comment: If it is not important to you to use the usualy mean, you can also try to minimize the variance of your estimatior $\hat x$ by using a weighted average, that takes the different $\sigma_i^2$ into account. This only makes sense if these $\sigma_i^2$ are not all close to eachother. Then you basically weight each measurements by a function of $\sigma_i^2$. It is however a little bit more complicated, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311177/minimize-combined-variance-of-multiple-measurements-with-known-but-varying-var)